# Odin the "share" config panel has disappeared

Tags: odin

At startup today I noticed on the latest version of Odin (stable) that the "share" panel is no longer present.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you be a bit more descriptive? What sort of sharing are you looking for? Sending a file to someone via a service? Or sharing media such as photos over the network? 

Comment: In system settings window on network section 

I've only 
Bluetooth, Online Account, Network icons

the share icôn is not longer present.
A+JYT